# Play Framework 1.2.4 - Crud - Inner object list

Tags: playframework, crud

I have an object `(Manager)` with a list of another object `(ActionItems)`. With both these objects I am using the CRUD module from which I override the `Managers/show.html` but I want to show all the action Items belong to a `Manager` on the same page. The `ActionItems` should only be available by selecting the manager object. How do I go about this?

```
public class Manager extends Model{
   ...
   public List<ActionItem> actions;
   ...
}

public class ActionItem extends Model{
 ...
}

public class Managers extends CRUD{

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no simple way to do this. More customization - more code.

### Managers/show.html

```
#{extends 'CRUD/layout.html' /}
#{set title:messages.get('crud.show.title', type.modelName) /}

<div id="crudShow" class="${type.name}">

  <h2 id="crudShowTitle">&{'crud.show.title', type.modelName}</h2>

  <div class="objectForm">
  #{form action:@save(object._key()), enctype:'multipart/form-data'}

    *{
    * You must hide default output of the crud.form for the "actions" field.
    * Just specify all fields of the Manager except the "actions".
   }*

    #{crud.form fields:['someField1', 'someField2', 'someField4'] /}

    *{
    * Now you can draw some list that contains all manager`s actions.
   }*

    <ul>
      #{list items:'object.actions', as:'action'}
       <li>
        <a href="@{Actions.show(action.id)}">${action}</a>
       </li>
      #{/list}
    </ul>

    *{
    * For adding a new action you need a something like link below.
    * There we try to retieve Manager`s id in the Action`s blank
    * method. Than we could try to modify blank() and intercept id for
    * our purposes.
   }*
    <a href="@{Actions.blank(object.id)}">Add new action</a>

    <p class="crudButtons">
      <input type="submit" name="_save" value="&{'crud.save', type.modelName}" />
      <input type="submit" name="_saveAndContinue" value="&{'crud.saveAndContinue', type.modelName}" />
    </p>
  #{/form}
  </div>

  #{form @delete(object._key())}
    <p class="crudDelete">
      <input type="submit" value="&{'crud.delete', type.modelName}" />
    </p>
  #{/form}

</div>
```

### Actions.java

```
public class Actions extends CRUD {

    // ...

    /** 
     * Modifed blank() method, that will retieve managerId to
     * Actions/blank.html, that will retieve it into modifed create()
     * method.
     */
    public static void blank(Long managerId) throws Exception {
        ObjectType type = ObjectType.get(getControllerClass());
        notFoundIfNull(type);
        Constructor<?> constructor = type.entityClass.getDeclaredConstructor();
        constructor.setAccessible(true);
        Model object = (Model) constructor.newInstance();
        try {
            render(type, object, managerId);
        } catch (TemplateNotFoundException e) {
            render("CRUD/blank.html", type, object, managerId);
        }
    }

    /** 
     * Modifed create() method.
     */
    public static void create(Long managerId) throws Exception {
        ObjectType type = ObjectType.get(getControllerClass());
        notFoundIfNull(type);
        Constructor<?> constructor = type.entityClass.getDeclaredConstructor();
        constructor.setAccessible(true);
        Model object = (Model) constructor.newInstance();
        Binder.bindBean(params.getRootParamNode(), "object", object);
        validation.valid(object);
        if (validation.hasErrors()) {
            renderArgs.put("error", play.i18n.Messages.get("crud.hasErrors"));
            try {
                render(request.controller.replace(".", "/") + "/blank.html", type, object);
            } catch (TemplateNotFoundException e) {
                render("CRUD/blank.html", type, object);
            }
        }
        object._save();

        /* Custom part {{{ */
        Manager manager = Manager.findById(managerId);
        manager.actions.add(object);

        flash.success(play.i18n.Messages.get("crud.created", type.modelName));
        if (params.get("_save") != null) {
            Managers.show(managerId);
        }
        if (params.get("_saveAndAddAnother") != null) {
            Actions.blank(managerId);
        }
        Actions.show(object._key(), managerId);
        /* }}} */
    }

    /** 
     * Modifed show() method.
     */
    public static void show(String id, managerId) throws Exception {
        // ...
    }

    // Other modifed methods... if need.

    // ...

}
```

### Actions/blank.html

```
#{extends 'CRUD/layout.html' /}
#{set title:messages.get('crud.blank.title', type.modelName) /}

<div id="crudBlank" class="${type.name}">

    <h2 id="crudBlankTitle">&{'crud.blank.title', type.modelName}</h2>

    <div class="objectForm">

    *{
    * Here we retieve managerId to modifed Actions.create().
   }*

    #{form action:@create(managerId), enctype:'multipart/form-data'}
        #{crud.form /}
        <p class="crudButtons">
            <input type="submit" name="_save" value="&{'crud.save', type.modelName}" />
            <input type="submit" name="_saveAndContinue" value="&{'crud.saveAndContinue', type.modelName}" />
            <input type="submit" name="_saveAndAddAnother" value="&{'crud.saveAndAddAnother', type.modelName}" />
        </p>
    #{/form}
    </div>

</div>
```

Something like this I did at your place.